# How to use String as Source When Adding PowerQuery

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm trying to add the String `filename` as my source for adding a PowerQuery Connection, but for some reason Excel is not picking up on the string? Any ideas? If I add the full path as text it works well.

My error is on the line `Csv.Document(File.Contents(filename)`

```
Sub AddQuery()
Dim newdate As Range
Set newdate = Range("E2")
Do Until Dir("D:\Users\rosenberggitty2\Dropbox\Personal\Done\Options\" & newdate.Text & ".csv") <> vbNullString
newdate = newdate + 1
Worksheets(1).Columns(5).AutoFit
Loop

Dim filename As String
filename = "D:\Users\rosenberggitty2\Dropbox\Personal\Done\Options\" & newdate.Text & ".csv"

Dim myConnection As WorkbookConnection
Dim mFormula As String
mFormula = _
"let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(filename),null,""#(tab)"",null,1252) in Source"
query1 = ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add(newdate, mFormula)

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to concatenate in with `&`...

Comment: @BigBen don't think that's the issue. It works well if I enter `""D:\Users\rosenberggitty2\Dropbox\Personal\Done\Options\" & newdate.Text & ".csv""` instead of `filename`

Comment: `filename` *inside* a String is just the text "filename", not the variable, so yes it is a problem.

Comment: @BigBen so your suggestion is that I change to `in & Source"`?

Comment: You have to concatenate in the `filename` in `File.Contents(filename)` IIUC. `mFormula` is just a long `String`... so it has the literal text "filename" instead of your actual filename.

Comment: Got it. I tried changing to `(File.Contents" & (filename) & "`, and while the code now picks up `(filename)` as the correct String, when I check the Connection it's blank with the error  `Expression.SyntaxError: Token Comma expected.`

Comment: Those parentheses should be inside the quotes, not outside them.

Comment: Error persists even after changing to `(File.Contents(" & filename & ")`

Comment: Highly suggest you `Debug.Print mFormula` and compare the output to what it should be if the filename were hard-coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Needs to have 3 sets of quotation marks for the path to be recognized correctly. `File.Contents(""" & filename & """)` Here's my updated code (includes some changes to the query).

```
Sub AddQuery()
Dim newdate As Range
Set newdate = Range("E2")
Do Until Dir("D:\Users\rosenberggitty2\Dropbox\Personal\Done\Options\" & newdate.Text & ".csv") <> vbNullString
newdate = newdate + 1
Worksheets(1).Columns(5).AutoFit
Loop

Dim filename As String
filename = "D:\Users\rosenberggitty2\Dropbox\Personal\Done\Options\" & newdate.Text & ".csv"


ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=newdate, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & filename & """),[Delimiter="","", Columns=26, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {" & _
        """Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}, {""Column17"", type text}, {""Column18"", type text}, {""Column19"", type te" & _
        "xt}, {""Column20"", type text}, {""Column21"", type text}, {""Column22"", type text}, {""Column23"", type text}, {""Column24"", type text}, {""Column25"", type text}, {""Column26"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"""


End Sub
```